# Flume-NG: How to Automate the reading of newly added files in a directory(Source of a Flume agent) using Flume-ng

Tags: hadoop, streaming, flume, flume-ng

spooldir option is there to stream all the files of a particular directory.
Once the entire reading of directory done, the job will pause/stop. But if i would like to add the new file into that same directory, what happens??

My requirement is to stream that directory when any new file added to that particular spooldir folder.

Please advice !!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spool directory source will keep reading files whenever they appear in the directory, it does not pause after processing set of files that were present in the directory when flume started. This is what documentation says 
"This source lets you ingest data by placing files to be ingested into a “spooling” directory on disk. This source will watch the specified directory for new files, and will parse events out of new files as they appear."

Comment: After setting agent1.sources.source1.fileHeader = true this property its started streaming